# Different Price for same product in different areas Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

We have a Opencart system setup for our e-commerce website.
But the problem, we are facing is that **there are lots of product with different MRP's in different areas of country**.
So we also need to show **different prices of same product in different areas**.
Is there a way to handle such situation in opencart already?
Or 
If not , how to go about solving the same, any ideas?
There will be no problem developing the solution , **just need a better approach for the same** according to opencart.

Comment: what does this mean: *'There will be no problem developing the solution'*?  Are you looking for a developer or is this question related to an actual programming issue you've encountered?

Comment: Don't need any developer , as i said just need an approach how to get this done to handle such scenerio?

Comment: sounds like you need a developer.  if not, please post some code or something you've tried and illustrate where it's failing and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

try this open cart extension,

```
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6068
```

or try this,

```
http://www.pavothemes.com/blog/tutorials/124-how-to-use-opencart-options-to-setup-different-variation-for-one-product.html
```

Comment: This extension provide different price with different currency, but in my case currency is also same.